# Swup page transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, swup

I'm playing around with Barba.js and Swup.js transition libraries in very stripped back form.

I have the transitions working fine, but the hard-coded "is-active" class to highlight the menu buttons in the menu is now not working - I assume because of the way that Swup caches pages? The mobile version of the same page is experiencing issues as well - the hamburger and slide out menu work fine, but the links have stopped working.

I've tried adding the class="transition-fade" to each button as per the documentation, and I'm surprised that the transitions are working without being added to any buttons! Am I missing something here...?

I've created a Stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-geo8vq?file=index.html

Any help with getting my head around getting this working along with any best practices would be greatly appreciated!

Andy